# magento menus of custom module no working

Tags: magento

I am having a custom module. I want it to appear in the permissions section. I define menus in my config.xml file as -

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Inventory_Uploads>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </Inventory_Uploads>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <uploads>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Inventory_Uploads</module>
                    <frontName>uploads</frontName>
                </args>
            </uploads>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <uploads>
                    <file>uploads.xml</file>
                </uploads>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <uploads>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Inventory_Uploads</module>
                    <frontName>uploads</frontName>
                </args>
            </uploads>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <uploads module="uploads">
                <title>Band Config</title>
                <sort_order>71</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <sub_menu1 translate="title">
                         <title>Config Menu</title>
                         <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                         <action>uploads/adminhtml_uploads</action>
                    </sub_menu1> 
                </children>
            </uploads>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <uploads translate="title" module="uploads">
                            <title>Band Config</title>
                            <sort_order>71</sort_order>
                            <action>uploads/adminhtml_uploads</action>
                            <children>
                                <items module="uploads">
                                    <title>Config Menu</title>
                                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                                    <action>uploads/adminhtml_uploads</action>
                                </items>
                            </children> 
                        </uploads>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>


        <layout>
            <updates>
                <uploads>
                    <file>uploads.xml</file>
                </uploads>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <global>
         <models>
            <uploads>
                <class>Inventory_Uploads_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>uploads_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </uploads>
            <uploads_mysql4>
                <class>Inventory_Uploads_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <order><table>admin_user</table></order>
                </entities>
            </uploads_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <uploads_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Inventory_Uploads</module>
                    <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </uploads_setup>
            <uploads_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </uploads_write>
            <uploads_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </uploads_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <uploads>
                <class>Inventory_Uploads_Block</class>
            </uploads>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <uploads>
                <class>Inventory_Uploads_Helper</class>
            </uploads>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

It appears in the permission section. When I select them and save, they gets saved properly. But when I assign that role to any user and login then sub-menu not appears there. It only shows "Band Config" as menu but does not show it's submenu  "Config Menu". Is there any tag error in xml?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the children in  section must be the same as defined in your  section, sub_menu1.

Try with this configuration :

```
<acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <uploads translate="title" module="uploads">
                            <title>Band Config</title>
                            <sort_order>71</sort_order>
                            <action>uploads/adminhtml_uploads</action>
                            <children>
                                <sub_menu1 module="uploads">
                                    <title>Config Menu</title>
                                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                                    <action>uploads/adminhtml_uploads</action>
                                </sub_menu1>
                            </children> 
                        </uploads>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
```